# Mongodb and Node js

Tags: stack, schema, mean

i am new in node js, and I am trying to build an app quiz engine using node js and mongo DB. I am  not sure what I need to make a schema for quiz engine. So anyone can help me.

Comment: Please try to be more specific about your Questions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a User Schema...

```
var userSchema = new Schema({

    name: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
});
```

But like the comment stated, you will have to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i can guess, a quiz will be given by user and it will have questions. So, you can make two entities :

i)  User entity
ii) Quiz/Questions entity

User entity schema :

```
module.exports = {
   attributes = {
     name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
  }
};
```

Question entity schema :

```
module.exports = {
   attributes = {
     questionLabel: {
        type: 'String',
        required: true
    },
    choices: {
        type: 'Array',
        required: true
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello this is my schema

```
enter code here var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var img_schema = new Schema({
    title:{type:String,require:true},
    creator:{type:Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" },
    extension:{type:String,require:true},
    foto:{type:String,require:true},
    uso:{type:String,require:true}
 });

var Imagen = mongoose.model("Imagen",img_schema);
 module.exports = Imagen;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
This is the example of user schema. you can replace with your requirement.

// User Schema
var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        index: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String
    },
    email: {
        type: String
    },
    name: {
        type: String
    },
    profileimage:{
        type: String
    }
});

var User = module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to use mongoose to define your mongoDB collection schemas. Mongoose facilitates a lot of processes between nodejs and mongoDB.
You can install mongoose using following command:

```
npm i mongoose
```

Then create a schema like this:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
const { Schema } = mongoose; //Pulling schema out of mongoose object

const QuizEngineSchema = new Schema({
 name: String,
 phoneNumber: Number,
 // other data that you need to save in your model
},
{timestamps: true},
{id: false});

//Plugging the Schema into the model
const QuizEngine = mongoose.Model('QuizEngine',QuizEngineSchema);

export default QuizEngine;
```

Hope this helps!